# Select table based on GET variable

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, sql

i'm a iphone programmer, and not so great in php and mysql. My question is that i have a online highscore system, which has 3 tables for all my modes in the game. I am trying to select the table based on the input from a GET variable, but it doesn't work. This is my code in php.

```
   $typeGame = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type']  : "";
    $typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
    if ($typeGame === "Sprint") {
$table = "highscoresSprint";
    }
    else if ($typeGame === "Normal")
    {
    $table = "highscoresNormal";
    }
    else
    {
    $table = "highscoresMarathon"; 
    }
```

Where typeGame the type of game is which is requested, and $table the table is.

I hope that you can help me, it just won't work.

Cheers, Joe.

Comment: any error outputted ? what does `echo $_GET['type']` returns? and the url has to be something like `http://test.com/game?type=Sprint`

Comment: @Furgas's answer should do it

Comment: i know, had to wait 4 minutes to accept :P, Classic case of wrong variable names, sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($typeGame);
```

instead of:

```
$typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that solved my problem, i will accept it in 4 mins. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$typeGame = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type']  : "";
//You don't need this - >$typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
if ($typeGame == "Sprint") {  // Change to == instead of ===
$table = "highscoresSprint";
} else if ($typeGame == "Normal") // Change to == instead of ===
{ 
$table = "highscoresNormal";
}
else
{
$table = "highscoresMarathon"; 
}
```

Comment: Why not ===? My personal rule: use === (or !==) when you are certain what type to expect.

Comment: Good point @Furgas.  Also I think using `mysql_real_escape_string` is proper since it's a variable being put into your SQL string that could be modified via the URL.

Comment: But it's not the variable being passed into his query, at least that's not the way I read it. I didn't see the need to explicitly compare the type and I don't usually for strings. But you still make a good point Furgas, maybe I'll start implementing that

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
> ```

I guess you want to say:

> $typeGame = mysql_real_escape_string($typeGame);

Answer (score 0):

Furgas answer will fix the issue, however I have a thing against seeing nested elses where a switch would so, so just wanted to post this up

```
switch (
    mysql_real_escape_string(
        isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type']  : ''
    )
) {
    case 'Sprint':
        $table = "highscoresSprint"; 
        break;
    case 'Normal':
        $table = "highscoresNormal"; 
        break;
    default:
        $table = "highscoresMarathon"; 
        break;
}
```